# i have using been kendo tree view for navigation purpose.and in the time of load i want all the nodes to visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

i have been  using been kendo tree view for navigation purpose and at the time of load i want all the nodes to visible so i have searched in internet and added the following  jquery

```
var tree = $("#kendoTreeview").data("kendoTreeView");
tree.expand(".k-item");
```

I get following error

> JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'expand' of undefined or null reference.

and I don't know how to solve this problem. Why do i get this error and in jquery is there any method called expand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means that `tree` is either `null` or `undefined` when you execute `tree.expand(".k-item");`.

- Did you verify that `tree` is actually a KendoUI TreeView object?
- Did you have created the `TreeView` in advance? You show code for getting a reference to it but that code does not actually create it.
- Is the `id` of the `TreeView` actually `#kendoTreeview` (is the spelling correct)?

Comment: sure man i got it but on loading data from remote it only loads the first parent node on clicking  it loads the child node i want every parent node and child node on page load itself